# finding the time stamp on phot's that have been emailed to me

Tags: iphone, email, photos

I'm having a dispute with a landlord, garden not done, so she's charging me. Anyway, the agency has sent me her photos. is there anyway I can see when they were taken. I check the properties of the photos and yet they only give todays date, but they do tell me longitude and latitude and that they were taken with and iPhone 4 plus f number if there was a flash etc but not the date taken.

Do is there a way for me to extract this information if the photos were emailed to me?

Comment: What device and OS are you using to detect the information?

Answer (score 2):

Open it in Preview.

Hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>i</kbd>   for Inspector, then the 2nd tab (info, i in a circle) & then Exif - should give full info, unless the originator was clever enough to remove it.

[image]

It is possible that the sender has set iOS to strip these fields from the photos and it's also possible that they are stripped if the image size is reduced. You can also use tools to manipulate / falsify the data, but in most cases people don't mess with changing the defaults.